# Xcode format pre-generated code

Tags: iphone, xcode, formatting, default

I have a particular format that I like to put my code in, and every time I create a new `UIViewController` (or any other class for that matter), the same auto-generated code from Apple is put in, and I have to spend the 2 minutes cleaning it up to be formatted the way I want it before I can even start.

I was wondering if there was a way to set it in Xcode to add in my version of the formatted code, so that I don't have to waste my time re-formatting. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XCode 4 changes how templates work, and where templates go, so be careful following instructions unless they refer to XCode 4.  You can find a few template examples, and the paths to where they go in my XCode4 customization repository:

https://github.com/KiGi/XCode4Customization

The paths where the system templates live is:

**/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/ Xcode/Templates/File Templates**

Don't change those, copy and modify in your own library directory:

**~/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData/File Templates**

Those paths are also in the "WhereToPlaceFiles" RTF file on github.

Answer (score 2):

You will find all the templates that Xcode uses when you create new files in /Developer/Library/Xcode/Templates.  Have a look in their, you should be able to figure out how it all words easily.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Note that is the old path, XCode 4 places files in a different location.

Comment: Where is it located in XCode 4?

Comment: That may be a left over relic from my Xcode 3 installation.  Where is it located in Xcode 4?

Answer (score 1):

Some options:

1. Learn to be ok with the format
2. Write code to fix it
3. Make your own UIViewController template that makes it the way you want

   http://blog.carbonfive.com/2009/05/19/custom-xcode-template-for-iphone-development/

Answer (score 1):

you can write your own templates (as others have detailed), and/or just run your sources through a code formatter ([uncrustify](http://uncrustify.sourceforge.net/) works well on objc sources).